# How to integrate Google checkout in my Android app?

Tags: android, google-checkout

I am developing one app , which is required to integrate Google checkout.I am searched lot of things on it but I didn't succeeded.I tried with [This Link](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Custom_Processing_How_To.html#set_up). It doesn't work in android.The main problem is I can't initialize  ApiContext class, I am getting an error in it: Could not find class com.google.checkout.sdk.commands.ApiContext' and  I am initializing it in onCrete.

Comment: You need `Credit Card` payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going about it wrong. You should use the integrated payment system (which uses Google Checkout) that's built into Google Play/Marketplace. Start here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html

Comment: I have read this,but In-app billing can be implemented only in applications that you publish through Google Play.